# GNU screen: Bind sequence of commands to a key

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to bind a sequence of commands (like e.g. first go to a certain window and in a second step do something there) to a key. Is this possible in screen?
More general (since this would answer my question too): Is it possible to define a new command which is just a sequence of other already defined commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was just asked. The method is to add the following to your .screenrc:

Lets say you want to bind h to cmd1 cmd2 cmd3:

```
bind h eval "cmd1" "cmd2" "cmd3"
```

I have been told that double quotes are not necessary. Thinking about this for a second, if your commands have arguments, you would need double quotes for sure. The trick is to use the eval command.